# How pass values dynamically from table to spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to pass values(objectName,Blocklist) dynamically from table reference.objectdata contains the below data.I am running this code in databricks

[image]

```
import io.delta.tables._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive,HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

val df =spark.read.table("reference.objectdata")

val objectname= df.("objectName")
var i=1

while(i<=df.count())
{
  val firstdf =DeltaTable.forName(s"$objectName")
  val timestampvalue  = firstdf.history(Blocklist).select("timestamp","operationMetrics")
  val w1 = timestampvalue.orderBy("timestamp")
  val w =w1.head
  
  i =i+1
  
  }
  
  
  Println(w)
```

Comment: What's your issue? What's the question?

Comment: You probably want to use a `map` or `flatMap` rather than the loop and mutable variable btw.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: I want to pass values 'objectName' and 'Blocklist' from table  reference.objectdata.         val firstdf =DeltaTable.forName(s"$objectName")
  val timestampvalue  = firstdf.history(Blocklist).select("timestamp","operationMetrics")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, you want something along these lines:

```scala
case class ObjectData(objectName: String, blocklist: Int)

// Retrieve the list of object names and blocklist
// You could also keep it as a Dataframe if you prefer 
val df: Dataset[ObjectData] = spark.read.table("reference.objectdata").as[ObjectData]

val df2: Dataset[X] = df.map { case ObjectData(objectName, blocklist) =>
  // For each object, execute a query that return a value of type X
  val something: X = DeltaTable.forName(objectName)
    ...
    .select(...)
    .orderBy(...)
    .head
  something 
}
```

*This is only a draft that you'll need to adapt for your exact needs and some types may be incorrect as I didn't try to compile it (I'm actually sure it doesn't compile!).*